# open a file with alternative programs using enter and cmd / super / alt based shortcuts

Tags: nautilus, 16.10, filemanager, file-association

I have the following need that can be generalized to (I think) several users.

60% of the time I open a certain file type (e.g., .pdf) with the default application (say evince), 35% with an other one (say xournal), and 5% with an other one (say gimp). Moreover I open this type of files at least 50 times per day. Going with the mouse over the file, right-click, go to "open with.." etc. is inefficient, while having:

- enter => evince
- ctrl + 2 + enter => xournal
- ctrl + 3 + enter => gimp
- etc.

would be much more comfortable.

I searched how to configure Nautilus to make it do this, but (as far as I understood) neither Cairo-dock nor xdotool seem to manage this case, plus I do not see other options.

Do you know if it is doable / how to do?

Notes:

- of course it may be "ctrl" or "shift" or "super", doesn't matter
- I hope that (but I do not know if) the solution can be generalized beyond Nautilus
- I would prefer a keyboard-only approach that does not involve using the mouse

Thank you people!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different solutions to pick from (demo examples for image files).

#### 1. xbindkeysrc

1) Install [xbindkeys.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xbindkeys)

2) Add to "~/.xbindkeysrc" the following:

```sh
"sleep 0.3 && xdotool key ctrl+c && PATH1=$(xsel -b) && nohup irfanview "$PATH1" >/dev/null & sleep 1 && wmctrl -x -r IrfanView -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz"
    Control + KP_Enter
"sleep 0.3 && xdotool key ctrl+c && PATH1=$(xsel -b) && nohup gimp "$PATH1" >/dev/null & sleep 1 && wmctrl -x -r Gimp -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && wmctrl -x -a Gimp"
    Alt + KP_Enter
```

3) rescan the config file for an update. In terminal:

```sh
xbindkeys -p
```

4a) adding 'click 1' before 'key ctrl+c' will make it open the file which is currently under the cursor instead of the currently selected file.

4b) if it's stuttering on your system, adjusting the 'sleep x' values might help.

#### 2. Thunar

This solution requires Thunar and takes a bit longer to open a file.

1. Install [Thunar.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunar)

2. Configure Thunar:

Super / Win key →  Thunar → Edit → Configure Custom actions → + → [Name: nomacs1; Command: nomacs %f; Keyboard Shortcut: → Alt + Enter] → Appearance Conditions → Image Files → OK

3. Works afterwards by selecting an image file (inside a Thunar window) and using the shortcut.